# How to add a tab with calculated fields in TFS work itemss

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to find some documentation in how to create a custom tab on tfs work items in order to show some fields which are calculated (not editable) and data comes from other systems.

[image]

However I cant find documentation about this, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing at first glance sounds like a modification to the [process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243782.aspx). However, the part about the data coming from other systems makes it a bit trickier, as the process template simply controls the information available on the work item form and its layout.

It sounds like what you really want is an [extension](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/extensions/overview), so you can extend the behavior of the work item form. Extensions will be available in on-premise TFS as of TFS 2015 Update 2.

Comment: if they will be available on tfs 2015 update 2, how did these guys already developed it for previous versions of TFS? www.tfs-timetracker.com?

Comment: If I had to guess, that application either used a previous iteration of the API (which as far as I know is undocumented and deprecated) or directly made changes to the TFS app tier, which is in general a bad idea.